# Concatenate date values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table that contains duplicate values in the columns `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5`.
I want to list all the dates in the row that contain the values generated the group by function.

```
datum          c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    number
2001-04-22     1     2     3     4     5     2
1999-08-24     2     3     4     5     6     2
2005-11-08     2     4     5     6     7     2
1998-03-20     1     2     3     4     5     2
2009-07-02     2     3     4     5     6     2
1996-05-21     2     4     5     6     7     2
```

Result should look like this:

```
datum                      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    number
1998-03-20 , 2001-04-22    1     2     3     4     5     2
1999-08-24 , 2009-07-02    2     3     4     5     6     2
1996-05-21 , 2005-11 08    2     4     5     6     7     2
```

in the source table can be duplicate values ​​in all columns, what will be the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select string_agg(to_char(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), ','),
       c1, 
       c2,
       c3, 
       c4, 
       c5, 
       number
from some_table
group by c1, c2,c3, c4, c5, number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with an [`array of date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html) in the result you can use the simple and fast [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

If you want the array (or list) in a specific order add `ORDER BY` in the aggregate function. I quote [the manual at the same page:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

> This ordering is unspecified by default, but can be controlled by writing
>   an `ORDER BY` clause within the aggregate call [...]

```
SELECT array_agg(datum ORDER BY datum) AS datum_arr
      ,c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
      ,min(number) AS number  -- you did not specify how to aggregate number
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY c1, c2,c3, c4, c5;
```